# Как сделать пробел после каждого 4-ого символа

Tags: css, vue.js

У меня есть переменная в которой храниться большое число, хотел сделать так, чтобы после каждого 4-ого символа был пробел, можно сказать как карточка?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         bank: 4789658715875258
      }
   },
   methods: {
      
   }
});
```

```css
.acount {
   width: 352px;
   height: 90px;
   background: green;
   border-radius: 24px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
.numamount {
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 22px;
   letter-spacing: -0.04em;
   color: #000000;
}
.bank__accout {
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: get-vh(32px);
   line-height: get-vh(30px);
   letter-spacing: -0.04em;
   color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="acount">
                           <div class="numamount">Номер счета</div>
                           <div class="bank__accout">{{bank}}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй встроенные фильтры во vue, вот ф-ия для фильтра:

```
prettify(num) => {
    const str = num.toString();
    return +str.replace(/(\d{1,4}(?=(?:\d\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))/g, "$1" + ' ');
}
```